# Is it possible to abort a HTTP request depending on the `Content-Type` when using Perl's LWP?

Tags: perl, http, lwp

I want my script to download only text/html content and not binary or images that could take significantly more time to download. I know about the [max_size](http://search.cpan.org/~gaas/libwww-perl-6.04/lib/LWP/UserAgent.pm) parameter but I would like to add a check on the `Content-Type` header. Is this doable ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As pointed out by others you can perform a `HEAD` request before your `GET` request. You ought to do this as a way of being polite to the server because it actually is easy for you to abort the connection, but not necessarily easy for the web server to abort sending a bunch of data and doing a bunch of work on its end.

There are some different ways to do this depending on how sophisticated you want to be.

1. You can send an `Accept` header with your request which only lists `text/html`. A well-implemented HTTP server will return a `406 Not Acceptable` status if you say you don't accept whatever it is the file is. Of course, they might send it to you anyway. You can do this as your `HEAD` request as well.
2. When using a recent version of [LWP::UserAgent](http://metacpan.org/module/LWP::UserAgent), you can use a handler subroutine to abort the rest of the request after the headers and before the content body.

   ```
   use LWP::UserAgent;
   use Try::Tiny; 

   my $ua = LWP::UserAgent->new;
   $ua->add_handler( response_header => sub {
       my($response, $ua, $h) = @_;

       die "Not HTML" unless $response->content_type eq 'text/html';
   });

   my $url = "http://example.com/foo";

   my $html;
   my $head_response = $ua->head($url, Accept => "text/html");
   if ($head_response->is_success) {
       my $get_response = $ua->get($url, Accept => "text/html");
       if ($get_response->is_success) {
           $html = $get_response->content;
       }
   }
   ```

See the [Handlers](https://metacpan.org/module/LWP::UserAgent#Handlers) section of the LWP::UserAgent documentation for details on handlers.

I haven't caught the exception thrown or made sure to deal with the 406 responses carefully here. I leave that as an exercise for the reader.

Comment: I believe some servers might send you the content of the file on a `HEAD` request as well. You probably also need to check for `405 Method Not Allowed` responses on the `HEAD` request and see if you can submit the `GET` request anyway if the `HEAD` fails with that response.

Comment: `HEAD` is not reliable, and it seems to me that anything that "properly" handles a `HEAD` request will also "properly" handle a `Accept` header. I would skip the HEAD request and use only the other two mechanisms (`Accept` and callback).

Comment: The add_handler() thing does exactly what I was looking for. Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

You can use the HEAD request to query the URI's header info. If the server responds to heads, you'll get everything that a GET would have returned, except for that pesky body.

You can then decide what to do based on the MIME type.

otherwise, you'll have to rely on the file's extension, before you request it.

Comment: This will indeed work but is a bit suboptimal as it doubles the number of requests in the nominal case. I get very few binary links so I would prefer abort these ones rather than adding a test for each link.

Comment: So why can't you determine file type from file extension before issuing the GET?

Comment: well... I have some cases where there isn't a single extension. Especially cgi scripts that send binary data... So this is not really reliable.

Comment: You can't tell from the tag whence the URI came?

Comment: what tag ? What I'm doing is a bot that examines the contents of web pages it encounters. I have no control over what type of links it might come into.

Comment: You can typically discern images from links ( <IMG> vs <A> ).

Comment: yea but links are out of context so I don't have any <img> or <a>. Anyway, the add_handler() thing is working fine :-)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the minimal `LWP::Simple` subclass of `LWP` then the `head` function returns the content type as the first element of a list.

So you can write

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use LWP::Simple;

for my $url ('http://www.bbc.co.uk') {
  my ($ctype) = head $url;
  my $content = get $url if $ctype eq 'text/html';
}
```